# Why does Apache mod_rewrite remove the uri part?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm trying to configure Apache as an encryption proxy `https://chat.example.com` for our websoket server `http://localhost:8000` (on the same OS). I enabled mod_proxy, mod_proxy_http, mod_proxy_wstunnel, mod_rewrite and mod_ssl according to the official docs. 
Then I made a regular https GET request to the `https://chat.example.com/connection/info?t=123144343`, but Apache rewrote it to `http://localhost:8000/?t=123144343` instead of `http://localhost:8000/connection/info?t=123144343`. Why?

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName chat.example.com

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ws://localhost:8000/ [P,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8000/ [P,L]

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/example.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.com-chain.crt

    LogLevel rewrite:trace7
    ErrorLog /var/log/example.com/chat_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/example.com/chat_access.log io

</VirtualHost>
```

```
[Wed Dec 25 18:57:16.057448 2019] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 9604:tid 140105269184256] mod_rewrite.c(483): init rewrite engine with requested uri /connection/info, referer: https://example.com/personal/chats
[Wed Dec 25 18:57:16.057523 2019] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 9604:tid 140105269184256] mod_rewrite.c(483): applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/connection/info', referer: https://example.com/personal/chats
[Wed Dec 25 18:57:16.057566 2019] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 9604:tid 140105269184256] mod_rewrite.c(483): RewriteCond: input='' pattern='=websocket' [NC] => not-matched, referer: https://example.com/personal/chats
[Wed Dec 25 18:57:16.057600 2019] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 9604:tid 140105269184256] mod_rewrite.c(483): applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/connection/info', referer: https://example.com/personal/chats
[Wed Dec 25 18:57:16.057637 2019] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 9604:tid 140105269184256] mod_rewrite.c(483): RewriteCond: input='' pattern='!=websocket' [NC] => matched, referer: https://example.com/personal/chats
[Wed Dec 25 18:57:16.057670 2019] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 9604:tid 140105269184256] mod_rewrite.c(483): rewrite '/connection/info' -> 'http://localhost:8000/', referer: https://example.com/personal/chats
[Wed Dec 25 18:57:16.057702 2019] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 9604:tid 140105269184256] mod_rewrite.c(483): forcing proxy-throughput with http://localhost:8000/, referer: https://example.com/personal/chats
[Wed Dec 25 18:57:16.057735 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 9604:tid 140105269184256] mod_rewrite.c(483): go-ahead with proxy request proxy:http://localhost:8000/ [OK], referer: https://example.com/personal/chats
```

Comment: "I made a regular http GET request to the `http://chat.example.com/connection/info?t=123144343`" - That's HTTP (port 80), not HTTPS (port 443)? Or is that just a typo in your question?

Comment: Sorry, it's just a typo. fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ws://localhost:8000/ [P,L]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8000/ [P,L]
> ```

You are capturing the URL-path with the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, ie. `(.*)`. However, you are not making use of this captured URL-path in the *substitution* and simply rewriting to the document root: `http://localhost:8000/`. The query string is copied through to the *substitution* implicitly.

You need to include the captured URL-path in the *substitution* using the `$1` backreference. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ws://localhost:8000$1 [P,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8000$1 [P,L]
```

Note that in a *virtualhost* context, the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is root-relative and includes the slash prefix, so the slash should not be included in the *susbtitution* (unless omitted from the captured pattern).

If this fails to work, then try using the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
RewriteRule ^ ws://localhost:8000%{REQUEST_URI} [P,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://localhost:8000%{REQUEST_URI} [P,L]
```

**EDIT:** Although, rather confusingly, I see from the question history (as I was surprised I didn't see this initially) that the code block in your original question already included the `$1` backreference and it was only removed after your recent *edit*?! (Although, with how it was implemented, it would have resulted in a double slash at the start of the URl-path.)

Comment: Sorry. At the first time, I copied that configuration from the wrong vhost file. Thanks a lot! Now I undestand my error in detail.